# DefaultHTTPClient + chunked encoding

Tags: java, scala, apache-httpclient-4.x

Does org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient support chunked encoding?

I can't figure out why I always get this:

```
org.apache.http.TruncatedChunkException: Truncated chunk ( expected size: 16384; actual size: 13532)
```

A block of Scala code:

```
val method = new HttpGet(uri)
val client = new DefaultHttpClient()
val response = client.execute(method)

Option(response.getEntity).foreach(
  body => {
    io.Source.fromInputStream(body.getContent).
      getLines().foreach(line => doStuff(line))
  }
  response.getEntity.getContent.close()
)
```

Comment: Are you closing the client afterwards?

Comment: @Jk1 Pardon, now code is up-to-date. I close the stream:

response.getEntity.getContent.close()  client doesn't have close() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpClient fully supports chunk coding. You are getting this exception because the response message sent by the server is malformed.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it all was server's fault actually.